# sign up activity start and apperas while admob open app ad still not close by the user

Tags: firebase, admob

i have android app that has splash screen that pass the user to sign up activity,
in sign up activity there is firebase code:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
}
```

that pass the user to MainActivity directly if the user already sign in.
i want to show admob open app ad but there is a problem that the app pass to MainActivity automatically and not wait for the user press the continue to app button.
how can i deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code to the `OnClickListener` of the Continue button so it will be executed only when the button is pressed.

Comment: I didn't find how to catch the onclicklistener of the new open app ads

Comment: can u share the code that executes the ad ?

Comment: i do exactly like the tutorial.
the execute is at AppOpenManager and i don't know how i can change it

this tutorial : https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open-ads

Comment: which tutorial are u talking about ? u need to give all the details at the start so people can have a better idea of what to look for